# javascript remove header and footer on string

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, string, laravel

I Got a string value like this :

sample 
date : xxxxx 
account : xxxxx
page : 01/08 
===============================
1 010101 40000 transfer standart
2 010121 45000 transfer standart
3 030101 50000 transfer standart
4 040101 60000 transfer standart
...

sample 
date : xxxxx 
account : xxxxx
page : 02/08 
===============================
21 110101 40000 transfer standart
22 210121 45000 transfer standart
23 230101 50000 transfer standart
24 340101 60000 transfer standart
...

sample 
date : xxxxx 
account : xxxxx
page : 08/08 
===============================
81 110101 40000 transfer standart
82 210121 45000 transfer standart
83 230101 50000 transfer standart
84 340101 60000 transfer standart

TOTAL : 12312312312321 123123213321321 
COUNT : 84 
...

I want to remove all header :
sample 
date : xxxxx 
account : xxxxx
page : 01/08 
===============================

and footer

TOTAL : 12312312312321 123123213321321 
COUNT : 84 
...

I try with

```
var lines = $scope.data.split('\n');
var data2= lines.splice(0,5);
var newtext = lines.join('\n');
```

and i got my string with no header at page 01/08, but i cannot remove header for page 2 - 8 and footer.

Can Anyone show me what should i add ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the lines that start with a number you can do something like this:

```
var lines = $scope.data.split('\n');
var numberedLines = line.filter(function(line) {
    return line.trim().match(/^\d/); // regex match: true if the line starts with a digit
});
var newtext = numberedLines.join('\n');
```

browser support for [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is not complete. (No Internet Explorer 8). Many libraries have some kind of built in alternative. For example jQuery has [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

Comment: Now , I want to import this data to database mysql. should i save it first to a file or i can import it with this string ?

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the original string on `===============================` and then splitting each substring of that result on `sample`, like this:

```
var initial = $scope.data.split("===============================");
var sec01 = initial[1].split("sample")[0];
var sec02 = initial[2].split("sample")[0];
```

For me, given the first two sections of your input data gives:

```
1 010101 40000 transfer standart
2 010121 45000 transfer standart
3 030101 50000 transfer standart
4 040101 60000 transfer standart 

21 110101 40000 transfer standart
22 210121 45000 transfer standart
23 230101 50000 transfer standart
24 340101 60000 transfer standart
```

This will work in any browser.